# JavaScript name variable

Tags: javascript, local-storage, variable-names

I'm using Mozilla Firefox if that changes anything.

So I was developing a website, an accidentally set `name` variable to my name in some code, and then I fixed that. Shortly after, I fixed that, and name was still my name. I switched tabs on to a random website, and started typing `name`, and it automatically showed the variable as I press `n`. It was set to `""`. What's going on here?

I even went to a 404 page on my server to make sure it wasn't a script I had included on my page, and typed `var name = "a"` and went to another page, and `name` returned `"a"`. Does it act like a localStorage variable?

Comment: Do you mean the console returned name as "a"?

Comment: The global variable `name` is the name of the window.

Comment: `name` is reserved: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: @MatthewHerbst: It's not https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words . The page you linked to says it should not be used in a browser environment, which is correct, but that doesn't make it reserved (on a language level).

Comment: Have you tried from a different browser? If so, what happened?

Comment: The categories on that w3Schools page are a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a global that exists as a property on every `window`.